# In dual numbers, what number is represented by the following matrix?

Tags: complex-analysis, matrices

In [dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number), what number is represented by the following matrix?

\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Using the definition in the link, this matrix is not a dual number.

Comment: @Taladris its p-factor is 0 so it is clear dual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the transpose of the dual unit $\epsilon$. So if you  represent your duals by 
$ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ it will not correspond to any "real" number.

Comment: I have already found it is sometimes denoted $\epsilon'$. Also it seems, it is $i+\epsilon$?

Comment: hmm, if we denote $i : \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\-1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ then $ \epsilon - \epsilon^\prime=i$

Comment: the last matrix is $-i$.

Comment: It's again a matter of convention. Can you summarize the reasoning as a full answer? May be it will be interesting for the general public.

Comment: what reasoning do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Since the square of your matrix is $0$, I would say that your matrix is $\epsilon$.

Note that the representation given in the Wikipedia article you linked to is not the only representation using $2 \times 2$ real matrices.

Comment: If it were $\epsilon$, then subtracted by $\epsilon$ it would give 0. But it does not. Note that not only $\epsilon$ gives $0$ squared (for instance, $-\epsilon$).

Comment: If you're using the representation given in the Wikipedia article, then this matrix cannot be a dual number.

Comment: It is dual because p as defined here is 0 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_%C3%97_2_real_matrices#2.E2.80.89.C3.97.E2.80.892_real_matrices_as_complex_numbers